# Webscraping to a DataFrame

Tags: arrays, dataframe, dictionary, series

I am trying to get information from a website, and into a Dataframe, but I'm having some trouble.

I have extracted the data, but I'm trying to merge two dataframes, and reshape them into one. Here is what I have:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = 'https://www.civilaviation.gov.in/'
resp = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(resp.content.decode(), 'html.parser')

div = soup.find('div', {'class':'airport-col vande-bharat-col'})
div2 = soup.find('div', {'class':'airport-col airport-widget'})

div['class'] = 'Domestic traffic'
div2['class'] = 'International traffic'

dom = div.get_text()
intl = div2.get_text()


def str2frame(estr, sep = '\n', lineterm = '\n\n\n\n\n', set_header = True):
    dat = [x.split(sep) for x in estr.split(lineterm)][0:-1]
    df = pd.DataFrame(dat)
    if set_header:
        df = df.T.set_index(0, drop = True).T # flip, set ix, flip back
    return df


df1 = str2frame(dom)
df2 = str2frame(intl)

df1.rename(columns={"अन्तर्देशीय यातायात  Domestic traffic On 29 Jan 2023":"Domestic Traffic"}, inplace=True)
df2.rename(columns={"अंतर्राष्ट्रीय यातायात     International traffic On 29 Jan 2023":"International Traffic"}, inplace=True)
```

So now I get two separate DataFrames with all the information I want, but not in the format I want. The shape of my dataframes are 6,2(one of the columns is blank)... I need them merged into one dataframe that is 2,6. So basically I show

```
               Domestic Traffic
```

1   Departing flights   2,967
2   Departing Pax        4,24,224
3   Arriving flights    2,960
4   Arriving Pax         4,18,697
5   Aircraft movements  5,927
6   Airport footfalls    8,42,921

I would like to see two rows, one for domestic and one for international traffic, and each column based on the given values. I apologize if my question or my coding is unclear. This is my first time asking a question on this forum. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is the expected result but you could [`transform`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.transform.html) and [`concat`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.concat.html) your data:

```
pd.concat([
    df1.set_index(df1.columns[0]).T,
    df2.set_index(df2.columns[0]).T
]).reset_index()
```

##### Output

|  | 0 | Departing flights | Departing Pax | Arriving flights | Arriving Pax | Aircraft movements | Airport footfalls |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | अन्तर्देशीय यातायात Domestic traffic On 30 Jan 2023 | 2,862 | 4,07,957 | 2,864 | 4,04,799 | 5,726 | 8,12,756 |
| 1 | अंतर्राष्ट्रीय यातायात International traffic On 30 Jan 2023 | 433 | 90,957 | 516 | 82,036 | 949 | 1,72,993 |